# Convert String back to PDF

Tags: swift, cgpdfdocument

I'm receiving a response containing a `String` from our RPC server. This `String` is a `PDF` converted to a `String`. In my app I need to convert this string back to a `PDF` file. I tried a couple of solutions here on Stack but they didn't work form me.

The problem is that my function keeps throwing because it fails to convert my string to a `CGPDFDocument`. What am I doing wrong here?

This is the code I currently have.

```
final class PdfGenerator: PdfGeneratorInterface {

// MARK: PdfGeneratorProtocol
func generatePdf(string: String) throws -> CGPDFDocument {

    guard let
        data = string.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false),
        cfData = CFDataCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, UnsafePointer<UInt8>(data.bytes), data.length)
    else {
        throw PdfGeneratorException.UnsupportedFormatException
    }

    let cgDataProvider =  CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData(cfData)

    guard let cgPDFDocument = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithProvider(cgDataProvider) else {
        throw PdfGeneratorException.UnsupportedFormatException
    }

    return cgPDFDocument
}
```

}

PDF String content:

https://gist.github.com/Combidi/fa53f2d74e7ae177bb3885d5d640c13c

Thanks

Comment: `format: "@.pdf"` This is wrong. Just take the normal string content.

Comment: @EricD removed the formatString as you suggested, but it didn't fix my problem. It still fails to convert to `CGPDFDocument `

Comment: I noticed the following line in the console "failed to find PDF header: `%PDF' not found."

Comment: Could you give us an example of your pdf string as you receive it so that we can test and debug? Post it in a GitHub Gist, for example, and give back the link. Thanks.

Comment: @EricD I added the string value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as if the string you linked to is base64 encoded.  If you decode that, the result should be a "%PDF" string that you can use.